# AssertionError, altough the expected call looks same as actual call

Tags: python, django, mocking

I made a command in django which calls a function.
That function does a django orm call:

```
def get_notes():
    notes = Note.objects.filter(number=2, new=1)
    return [x.note for x in notes]
```

I want to patch the actual lookup:

```
@mock.patch('Note.objects.filter', autospec=True)
def test_get_all_notes(self, notes_mock):
    get_notes()
    notes_mock.assert_called_once_with(number=2, new=1)
```

I get the following assertion error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: filter(number=2, new=1)
Actual call: filter(number=2, new=1)
```

I search on google and stackoverflow for hours, but I still haven't a clue.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, I think it might be an obvious mistake I'm making...

Comment: Relevant, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883906/django-orm-mock-values-filter-chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use `patch()` like this. Patch target should be a string in the form `package.module.ClassName`. I don't know much about django but I suppose `Note` is a class so `Note.objects.filter` is not something you can import and hence use in `patch()`. Also I don't think `patch()` can handle attributes. Actually I don't quite understand why the patch works at all.

Try using `patch.object()` which is specifically designed to patch class attributes. It implies `Note` is already imported in your test module.

```
@mock.patch.object(Note, 'objects')
def test_get_all_notes(self, objects_mock):
    get_notes()
    objects_mock.filter.assert_called_once_with(number=2, new=1)
```

I've removed `autospec` because I'm not sure it will work correctly in this case. You can try putting it back if it works.

Another option might be to use `patch()` on whatever you get with `type(Note.objects)` (probably some django class).

As I've said I don't know much about django so I'm not sure if these things work.